# How do I use a dynamic library in Android Studio with C++?

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, shared-libraries

I have been trying to use a dynamic (shared) library in my android studio c++ game activity project, however my project does not open the shared library successfully, and I have been unable to find anything that works for me online. The shared library is a .so file generated from a Visual Studio project of type *Shared Library (Android, IOS)*. I am using Android Studio version 17.0.6, and Visual Studio 2022 version 17.7.6. I am on Windows 11.

So far I have tried creating a jniLibs folder inside my main folder and putting the appropriate subfolders (x86_64, arm64-v8a, ect.), and putting the appropriate .so file inside. I then load the library in my cmake.txt file, which works, but when I try and load the library inside my code it is unable to load the library. The code I use to try and load the library is the following:

```
add_library(libSharedLibrary SHARED IMPORTED)

set_target_properties(libSharedLibrary PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../jniLibs/${ANDROID_ABI}/SharedLibrary.so)
```

```
void callFunctionFromSharedLibrary() {
    void* handle = dlopen("C:path/to/SharedLibrary.so", RTLD_LAZY);

    if(handle) {
        aout << "Successfully loaded shared library" << std::endl;
        dlclose(handle);
    }
    else {
        aout << "Failure to load shared library" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Currently the code outputs a failure to load. I have checked the path is correct, reloaded and rebuilt the project, and recreated the shared library files. Another point of my concern is the Android Studio IDE does not seem to recognise the .so files. I am not sure if this is related to me being on windows, which uses DLLs, or if that means I cannot use this type of shared library. Any information would be appreciated. Please note I am a beginner in Android Studio so detailed explanations would be appreciated.

Comment: File paths on Android never starts with an `C:` therefore trying to load a library from that path can only fail on these platforms.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this I changed

```
void* handle = dlopen("C:path/to/SharedLibrary.so", RTLD_LAZY);
```

to

```
void* handle = dlopen("SharedLibrary.so", RTLD_LAZY);
```

which allowed to program to successfully load the shared library.